# what is DynamoDB's replication type?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, database-replication

What is the replication type of dynamoDB?

Im assuming it is peer-to-peer based on online results but can any confirm or deny?

Comment: https://quabase.sei.cmu.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Amazon_DynamoDB_Data_Replication_Features here it states peer to peer

Answer (score 2):

People often assume a connection between the [Dynamo Paper](https://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2007/10/amazons_dynamo.html) and DynamoDB, so they claim that DynamoDB uses leaderless replication.

However, DynamoDB is based on many principles of Dynamo, but it is not an implementation of Dynamo. See reference 4 of the [Wikipedia article on Dynamo](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamo_(storage_system)#Implementations) for a quote explaining that it uses single-leader replication.

Answer (score -1):

Dynamo had a **multi-leader** design requiring the client to resolve version conflicts and DynamoDB uses **synchronous replication** across multiple data centers for high durability and availability.